# Object Animator animations not working in fragments used in viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, animation, android-viewpager

It's a simple implementation of viewpager using FragmentStatePagerAdapter. 
There are 4 fragments in total.
This is the onCreateView method of one of the Fragments.

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.intro1, container, false);

    /** initializing Views **/
    initViews(view);

    startAnimation();

    return view;
}
```

All the fragments have exact same onCreateView method.
The startAnimation method for fragment 2 is here.

```
 private void startAnimations() {
    ObjectAnimator rotateTasks = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(viewTasks,"rotation",0f,360f);
    ObjectAnimator alphaTasks = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(viewTasks, "alpha",0f,1.0f);

    final ObjectAnimator alphaPaint = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(viewPaint,"alpha",0f,1.0f);
    final ObjectAnimator scaleXPaint = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(viewPaint,"scaleX",1.0f,1.2f);
    final ObjectAnimator scaleYPaint = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(viewPaint,"scaleY",1.0f,1.2f);

    taskAnimator = new AnimatorSet();
    taskAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator(-0.1f));
    taskAnimator.setDuration(DEFAULT_ANIMATION_DURATION);
    taskAnimator.play(rotateTasks)
            .with(alphaTasks)
            .with(alphaPaint)
            .with(scaleXPaint)
            .with(scaleYPaint);
    taskAnimator.start();
}
```

Now, what exactly happens is once the app runs, the animations play on all the fragments except for the fragments number 2. But the strange thing is when I swipe back from the fourth fragment to the 3rd and then to the 2nd, the animations plays for the 2nd fragment.

Comment: Can you please explain in brief

Comment: Object Animator animations are not working for fragment whose index is 1 in viewpager. For rest of fragments, it works.